# What's the formula for this 2D cellular automata pattern?

Tags: python, math, discrete-mathematics, cellular-automata

I am modelling the following Ulam system in Python, I can't figure out what the formula for this particular pattern is. I got this illustration from Wolfram's A New Kind of Science (2002).

Can anyone recognise the formula? I assumed that, starting with a single black cell in the middle(t=1), it would expand by one cell in each (orthogonal) direction for the next three steps then add 3 cells on each side at the 5th step.But it is not as repetitive as I thought.

[image]

Comment: [This page](https://www.wolframscience.com/nks/p171--cellular-automata/) talks about something similar. Maybe it helps as hint?

Comment: FWIW, the transitions must depend on more than just the 8 directly adjacent cells. This is evident from the fact that the branch tips grow only outwards in step 4, but branch out in step 5, even though the immediate 8-cell neighborhoods of the cells around the tips look the same in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Some things that jump out at me:

A cell, once born, never dies.

The rule appears to have four-fold symmetry.

Discontiguous cells never appear; to be born, a cell must be in contact with a living cell (in one of the four directions, I forget the name of that neighborhood).

A line of cells, growing out into empty space, grows forever. A line sometimes sprouts perpendicular lines, but those lines stop growing before they collide.

I suspect that the important distance is 2. That is, the future state of a point is determined by the 5x5 square of which it is the center; cells farther away don't matter.

Is that enough to go on?